# Logi Xml Pagination

Tags: web-applications, pagination

What I have is a stacked bar chart with three different values. When i click on the bar chart I have a data table that populates messages for this bar chart.

When i use pagination on it only allows me to have one page. What I mean is if i have 250 lines if i set Page row count to 300 it will show all these messages on one page.

What I want is to display 25 messages per page, so I will have 10 pages. When i click to go to the next pagethe tables defaults to no messages as before you click on the bar chart.

The problem is the data is being pulled in but it won't display on multiple pages.

So the data will only go on page 1 it won't go on more than one page.

Has anyone had this issues and found a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add a bit more details (maybe a code snippet from the .lgx file). Are you loading the table in the same report using RefreshElement, or in a separate report? Do you have ajax pagination, or regular? Does this happen in a clean environment (a project that contains this part only?)

In the meantime, what comes to mind is some request forwarding issues. Maybe adding a hidden input element for the bar ID(?)